# There are questions about creating blocks in bitcoin networks

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin

Does the node that created the new block in the bitcoin network start mining the next block?

Or do you start mining together after the blocks have been propagated to all the nodes?

If you are starting mining after the blocks have been propagated to all nodes, is there a way to verify that the blocks are propagating to all nodes participating in the bit coin network?

Comment: This question is off topic as it is not about programming. You may be able to get help on our sister site, [bitcoin.se].

Answer (score 0):

Node starts mining the next block immediately after it creates block.
Node may not even propagate a block, start mining next and then propagate 2 blocks in the same time. If other nodes didn't find 2 another blocks during this time, 2 blocks of our node becomes the part of the main chain.